# Web-to-Lead custom Return Url

Tags: wordpress, web2lead

With the Salesforce web-to-lead option, there is a return url that happens when form has been submitted. However it is static. But I would like info passed along from the form such as an email they provided. Is there a way to do this?

My scenario would be to use this in Wordpress and when the form is submitted, redirect the user to a thank you page and then send them an email/do some other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal HTML--you can manipulate the URL with JavaScript. Technically, this is outside the scope of this site, but as a simple example:

```
 <input name="email" onchange="updateRetURL(this)" />

 <script>
 function updateRetURL(input) {
   document.getElementById("retURL").value = 'https://my.wordpress.com/page?email='+input.value;
 }
 </script>
```

Note that if the user disables JavaScript, this won't work--and there's no way to make it work. The Web-to-Lead interface is rather minimal, so the only other alternative would be to host your own script on your site, then submit the Web-to-Lead data to the W2L endpoint, then redirect. You can do this in PHP, Perl, Ruby, or whatever other language your server supports.